# Trying to use websockets in qwebview with Qt 4.8

Tags: javascript, qt, websocket

I have a webpage that uses websockets to update various text fields periodically.  This page works as expected when opened in a modern web browser.  When I try to open up this page inside a QWebView the fields no longer update.

I checked for websocket support with:

```
QString mystr = "if (window.WebSocket) {alert('No WS Support');}";
view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(mystr);
```

Which results in an alert box so I assume that QWebView is not capable of working with websockets.  (This makes sense as I am stuck using Qt 4.8 which is rather old by this point)

**EDIT**

I see that I did the if statement incorrectly when testing for websocket support in javascript.  Either way I still am struggling to have the fields update in qwebview the same way they do on a modern browser.

---

Next I decided to try and use QSslSocket to perform the websocket upgrade request which seems to work alright.

Here is the code I have for that:

```
socket.connectToHost("127.0.0.1",80);
if(!socket.waitForConnected())
        qDebug() << socket.errorString();

qDebug()<<socket.write("GET /crown HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                           "Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n"
                           "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                           "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                           "Origin: http://127.0.0.1\r\n"
                           "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\n"
                           "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n"
                           "Sec-WebSocket-Key: WN3k1L3mft8HTM0bgZcP/A==\r\n"
                           "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n"
                           "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n"\r\n");
    while (socket.waitForReadyRead())
        qDebug() << socket.readAll().data();
```

The while loop and qDebug produce the appropriate upgrade response from the server along with a constant stream of my websocket data which again is what I expected and hoped for.

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 0GZNz5bqd8dtJE05JgVuk3LboEA=
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 000000000000
```

I am stuck at this point because the alert message still pops up saying no websocket support.  Is there a way to basically make the javascript and websockets that exist on this page work in QWebView?  I have tried looking into QNetworkAccessManager but the documentation on this class isn't providing me with enough understanding to determine if this is how I would enable the websocket functionality.

If anyone has any pointers for me it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `QString mystr = "if (window.WebSocket) {alert('WS Supported ');} else{alert('WS  not Supported ');}";` ?? or is it an error while pasting in the question?

Comment: You are correct.  So I guess that means I had websocket support all along.  Though this doesn't explain why the fields won't update in my webview but do in Chrome.

Comment: Your use of `QSslSocket` has nothing to do with whether `QWebView`'s javascript engine supports websockets correctly. I would edit out the `QSslSocket` code since it has nothing to do with your problem. If the websocket support proves problematic, one solution is to implement your own websocket object based on `QSslSocket` and expose it to the javascript engine, and use it instead of the js websocket.